# Retrolambda doesn't apply to a test build of an Android app

Tags: android, unit-testing, gradle, retrolambda

I have found that my android project isn't transformed by Retrolambda if it compiled to unit testing purposes.

Any submodule transformed correcty instead of the root application.

How can I force a RL trnsformations for a test purposes?